# How to return documents which were created between 2 timestamps using Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, angularfire

I want to load all the documents that were saved between 2 timestamps,  from my collection. I call a service function in my component.ts where I set as parameters the 2 timestamps I need. How could I query the database in order to return me the documents I want using ref.where

This function is located at my service

```
findItems(colId: string, timestamp1: Date, timestamp2: Date){
    return this.db.collection(`items/${colId}/stuff`,ref =>{
      return ref.where("createdAt", ">=", startTime );
        }).valueChanges()
    }
```

I call this function in my component as above

```
  public items: Observable<any>

this.myService.findItems(this.item.colId, this.item.time1, this.item.time2)
```

Actual field on One Item:

[image: createdAt field on one item]

Example Start/End Timestamps:

[image: example start/end timestamps]

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem combining where clauses with ranges [on the same field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).  But, you would need to be creating your data with the `createdAt` field, as Firestore doesn't timestamp its documents by default.  Its also not clear where `startTime` comes from in your code.

Comment: I will try ref.where("createdAt",">=",timestamp1).where("createdAt","<=",timestamp2) as I read on the link you provided, since I have add a timestamp to each product I created

Comment: If it doesn't work (I note the field name you're querying now is `created` not `createdAt`, please show some of the data from your database).  Its also possible you won't be able to directly compare to a Date object.

Comment: I checked the timestamps since I converted them to firestore format timestamps. I added some manually through db interface and some from my app and the had the same look. I will provide some photos in my post

Comment: Its not clear what these are images of, or even what the field names should be (now there are fields with `startTime` and `endTime` too.  Please show more context.

Comment: The first image is the field of createdAt timestamp when an item is created, and the second image which contains 2 timestamps is the start and end  timestamp. I have set a start and end timestamp in order to display the documents that where created between those 2 timestamps

Answer (score 0):

It is totally fine in Firestore to create a compound query using ranges on a field, as long as there is [only one field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) involved.  This, you shouldn't have a problem doing this.

Assuming that the `createdAt` field is being created on all documents in this collection as a Timestamp field, and `timestamp1` is always less than `timestamp2`, this code should generate a query that does what you're looking for and return the `Observable` you need:

```js
findItems(colId: string, timestamp1: Date, timestamp2: Date) {
    return this.db.collection(`items/${colId}/stuff`, ref => {
        return ref.where('createdAt', '>=', firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(timestamp1))
                  .where('createdAt', '<=', firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(timestamp2));
        }).valueChanges()
    }
```

This works in AngularFire assuming you have imported the `firestore` namespace, like so:

`import { firestore } from 'firebase';`

There is more complete documentation about how this fits into AngularFire [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md), though the documentation for `ValueChanges` and its caveats (such as not returning the document id) is [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md).

Comment: That works great using compound query. Do I need to subscribe to it after this service call -> this.myService.findItems(this.item.colId, this.item.time1, this.item.time2) in order to see the items ?

Comment: Like your original function, it returns an `Observable` for a synchronized array of JSON objects based on the data, so you can use it in any way you would an `Observable`.  The AngularFire documentation has a [great example](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#using-angularfirestorecollection) of how to use the result from `valueChanges()`.

Comment: Shorter answer: yes, you will need to subscribe to it at some point, but you can use it in a template, for example.